# Intellectual property at employee hackathon?

Tags: intellectual-property, employment

The company I am working for this summer is going to be hosting an hackathon for its summer interns. Out of idle curiosity, I asked about the IP rights for any resulting projects, and got the (not entirely  surprising) response that the company would own any resulting projects.

That got me thinking, though- is this legal? It's a company event for employees, yes, but it's taking place outside work hours with no compensation (aside from food and a few prizes), and projects may be totally unrelated to any existing IP owned by the company. Of course, it's entirely possible that there was some clause in the new hire paperwork about this, but outside of that, would this hold up in court?

Comment: I think this would depend entirely on the jurisdiction and the agreements they had signed.  Its most likely legal and sucks.

Comment: You say there is no compensation. Is the event mandatory?

Comment: What jurisdiction?  Will the additional hours mean any total compensation for the internship averages to less than any statutory minimum wage?

Answer (score 3):

"The company you are working for ..." Stop. We're done. An employer owns the IP created by an employee in the course of their employment: the hackathon is in the course of your employment.

Comment: If participants are paid regardless of whether they win, anything produced would be a work for hire.  A company could also specify that prize monies represent payment in full for any winning entries, but an unpaid participant who comes up with something really brilliant they want to keep could refuse the prize and keep their IP for themselves.  If a participant receives no consideration for their participation, a contract purporting to assign IP to the contest sponsor may or may not be valid depending upon whether "bragging rights" are regarded as consideration.

Comment: @supercat The participant has already received consideration: the opportunity to win a prize. That they may refuse that prize is no different from an employee who returns their paycheque - the other party has done everything promised so the contract is binding (and complete).

Comment: In the U.S., someone who does useful work at the behest of someone else must be paid at least minimum wage.  An employer may ask a prospective employee to perform a test in the hope of getting a job, without paying the prospective employee anything, but only if the prospective employee is not performing work that is useful to the employer (beyond providing insight into the prospective employees' abilities).  A contest may specify that a prize will be an offer to purchase exclusive rights to work done by someone therein, but I'm not sure labor laws would allow any claim of ownership...

Comment: ...of work done by people who were not, at the time they did the work, employees who would be paid whether or not they won.

Comment: @supercat this is not that situation. These are existing employees under an existing contract (which makes my other comment irrelevant here). Notwithstanding: the opportunity to be considered for a job is valuable consideration.

Comment: If the hack-a-thon is done during normal working hours, that would be true.  If it is done outside normal working hours, then an employer who wants ownership over everything should write a contract that makes that explicit; if a contract could plausibly be interpreted so as not to claim ownership, any such ambiguity would be interpreted against the party drafting it.  It's possible to write contest terms so that the sponsor acquires either ownership or a non-exclusive license to anything done therein, but absent an explicit spec I don't think the default position would claim full ownership.

Comment: @supercat if you work for me and work out of hours, you’re still working for me.